# Error: Since gap.degree parameter has length larger than 1, it should have same length as the number of sectors

Tags: r, error-handling, chord-diagram, chord

In R I would like to create a chord diagram showing the distribution of events, but more importantly all possible combinations of concurrent events that we can find for the subects. Inside the diagram I would like to see a sector for each event and these linked together according to the event combinations

This is my dataframe

```
data <- data.frame(
  subject_id =c( 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 10, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 18, 18, 18, 18, 21, 34, 34, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40),
  Stomachache = c( 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  Headache = c( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Diarrhoea = c( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
  Fever = c( 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Cramps = c( 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Vomiting = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)
```

This is my R code:

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(subject_id) %>%
  summarize(
    Stomachache= sum(Stomachache),
    Headache = sum(Headache),
    Diarrhoea = sum(Diarrhoea),
    Fever = sum(Fever),
    Cramps = sum(Cramps),
    Vomiting =sum(Vomiting)
  )
# Extract the event columns (excluding "USUBJID")
events <- as.matrix(data[, -1])

# Determine the number of sectors
num_sectors <- ncol(events)

# Create a matrix with event co-occurrence
co_occurrence <- t(events) %*% events

# Convert diagonal values to 0 (events do not co-occur with themselves)
diag(co_occurrence) <- 0

# Define the gap degrees between sectors in the chord diagram
num_sectors<-c(1,1,1,1,1)
gap_degree <-c(5,5,5,5,5)

chordDiagram(
  x = co_occurrence,
  transparency = 0.5,
  annotationTrack = "grid",
  preAllocateTracks = 1,
  preAllocateSize = 1,
  gap.degree = gap_degree
)
```

But I got this error: **Error: Since `gap.degree` parameter has length larger than 1, it should have same length as the
number of sectors.**

This is the idea (instead of company, I would like a sector for each event)

[image]

Comment: Hi Bibi. A couple of things to help clarify the question: 1) Your code for creating the sample `data` won't work since variables aren't the same length. 2) Where is the `chordDiagram` function coming from? Browsing the documentation for the `circlize` library I don't see `gap.after` or `preAllocateSize` arguments in that function. 3) Where is `num_sectors` being used? Your code defines it twice, but I don't see what its doing.

Comment: Hi @Seth ,thank you for your answer. 1) I've just corrected the dataset code, now they have same length, I am sorry for this. 2) It is circlize library, and regarding the gap.after or preAllocateSize, it is very likely that they are wrong. I found them in a web site. 3) Regarding num_sectors, I am confused! I would like to have one sector for each event (disease), so 6 sectors in total

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(circlize)
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>%
  group_by(subject_id) %>%
  summarize(
    Stomachache= sum(Stomachache),
    Headache = sum(Headache),
    Diarrhoea = sum(Diarrhoea),
    Fever = sum(Fever),
    Cramps = sum(Cramps),
    Vomiting =sum(Vomiting)
  )

events <- as.matrix(data[, -1])

# Determine the number of sectors
num_sectors <- ncol(events)

# Create a matrix with event co-occurrence
co_occurrence <- t(events) %*% events

# Convert diagonal values to 0 (events do not co-occur with themselves)
diag(co_occurrence) <- 0

# Define the gap degrees between sectors in the chord diagram

gap_degree <-rep(5, times = num_sectors)

circos.par(gap.after = gap_degree)

chordDiagram(
  x = co_occurrence,
  transparency = 0.5,
  preAllocateTracks = 1
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks really beautiful. Can you tell me how I can add event numbers outside the sectors or rather remove the numbers completely? (to me, too high numbers appear that do not correspond to events). Then, would it be possible to make a chord diagram showing the distribution of all events and only for event="STOMACHACHE", the concurrent events?

Comment: I am really sorry for all these questions